# Does hypochlorous acid oxidize hydrogen peroxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, aqueous-solution, oxidation-state

The following reaction is from https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/kech202.pdf, p. 11:

> $$\ce{H2O2 + HOCl -> H3O+ + Cl- + O2}$$

I have to find if $\ce{H2O2}$ is acting like a reducing agent or an oxidising agent in this reaction.

If we see, the $\ce{Cl}$ atom in $\ce{HOCl}$ got reduced from $+1$ to $-1$ oxidation  state. That tells me that $\ce{H2O2}$ is acting as a reducing agent. But if I see the $\ce{O}$ atom, it is oxidised from $-2$ to $0$,  now this tells me that $\ce{H2O2}$ is acting as a oxidising agent.

But how is this possible? I know I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Evaluate formal [oxidation numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxidation_state) of chlorine and oxygen, the answer to the question should be clear from the result.

Answer (score 4):

You are not doing much wrong except for assigning improper oxidation number to oxygen of the peroxo group.
If the redox reaction “*feels*” wrong, you can check yourself using a table of standard reduction potentials [1, p. 5-79]:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{H2\overset{-1}{O}_2 &<=> \overset{0}{O}_2 + 2 H+ + 2 e-} &\quad E^\circ_1 &= \pu{-0.695 V} \tag{1}\\
\ce{H\overset{+1}{Cl}O + H+ + 2 e- &<=> \overset{-1}{Cl}^- + H2O} &\quad E^\circ_2 &= \pu{+1.482 V} \tag{2}\\
\hline
\ce{H2\overset{-1}{O}_2 + H\overset{+1}{Cl}O &-> H3O+ + \overset{-1}{Cl}^- + \overset{0}{O}_2} &\quad E^\circ &= +\pu{0.787 V} \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Since resulting $E^\circ = \pu{0.787 V} > 0,$ free Gibbs energy $Δ_\mathrm{r}G^\circ = -nFE^\circ < 0,$ and the redox reaction where hydrogen peroxide is *oxidized* by chlorate(I) can be considered a thermodynamically favorable process.

Alternatively, you can use [Latimer diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latimer_diagram), which comes in handy for disproportionation and synproportionation reactions.

#### Reference

1. Haynes, W. M.; Lide, D. R.; Bruno, T. J. *CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics: A Ready-Reference Book of Chemical and Physical Data*, 97th ed.; Taylor & Francis Group (CRC Press): Boca Raton, FL, **2016**. ISBN 978-1-4987-5429-3.